# How to hide @main report text in crystal?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am using c# in winform and reporting with crystal report.

My issue is that when I run my report it shows the text "main report" at the top. I need to hide this text and its panel.

Comment: “Please help me” is [not a question we can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/). You need to [create a minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem and [post the code here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :.

```
this.Text.Visible=false
```

in your crystal reports forms load event